# Desestructurar objetos con las mismas propiedades

Tags: javascript

Hola tengo un objeto literal por ejemplo
`const persona = {nombre:"José", edad: 30};`
Cuando hago el destructuring funciona correctamente.
`const {nombre, edad} = persona;`
Hasta aquí todo correcto...
Lo que no logro es poder desestructurar dos objetos con las mis keys
`const persona = {nombre:"José", edad: 30};`
`const persona1 = {nombre:"Manuel", edad: 23};`
`const {nombre, edad} = persona;`
`const {nombre, edad} = persona1;`
La consola del navegador me muestra un error porque esas variables ya fueron declaradas.
Suponiendo que trabajo con una clase constructora que me crea objetos iguales donde lo que cambian son los valores.
Hay alguna manera de hacer destructuring a cada objeto sin crear alias para cada una de las variables?

Comment: No puedes usar los mismos nombres de constante o variable. Pero si das mas detalles de lo que quieres hacer con ellas, tal vez podamos sugerir algo. Por favor [edita tu pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/520030/edit) para explicar qué es exactamente lo que necesitas, en qué momento planeas usar esas variables y para qué.

Comment: Si, claramente en el poco código que pone el problema es el nombre duplicado de las constantes... para solucionarlo, la segunda linea podría ser `const {nombre1, edad1} = persona1;`... pero si nos aclara el tema de la suposicion de una clase constructora y nos da un ejemplo de lo que tiene le podemos ayudar

Answer (score 2):

La solución es simple. En primer lugar usa `let` en lugar de `const` ya que una variable `const` solo puede ser asignada una sola vez.

Declara las variables con `let` solo en la primera desestructuración, ya que en la segunda ya existen las variables. Usa paréntesis para sobreescribir las variables. Te adjunto un ejemplo:

```js
const persona = {nombre:"José", edad: 30};
const persona1 = {nombre:"Manuel", edad: 23};

let {nombre, edad} = persona;
({nombre, edad} = persona1);

console.log(nombre, edad)
```

Otra posible solución (no recomendada) es usando `var`:

```js
const persona = {nombre:"José", edad: 30};
const persona1 = {nombre:"Manuel", edad: 23};

var {nombre, edad} = persona;
var {nombre, edad} = persona1;

console.log(nombre, edad)
```